# How to make user to paste only digits into a text area box?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to make a textarea field allow only digits and enter keys which can be checked easily with,

```
 function validate(key) {

    // getting key code of pressed key
    var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
    var phn = document.getElementById('textarea');
    // comparing pressed keycodes
    if ((keycode < 48 || keycode > 57) && keycode !== 13) {
        return false;
    }


}

<div>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"  onkeypress="return validate(event)" />
</div>
```

But this functionality breaks if the ***user copy-paste something into the text area field***. How can I make user paste only if he has copied digits only, i.e

```
13131331        -        should be pasted
2wewewe12       -        should not be pasted
```

I don't do Javascript. Kindly suggest something?

Comment: Where's your event handler?

Comment: if you only want digits why are you using a textarea?

Comment: if they are pasting in, they arent going to get key presses for alpha-characters.   You will need to check for it in that textarea and then only keep it if the input string is only numerics

Comment: @sebnukem: It's a requirement from my client.

Comment: If possible, tell your client that a **text**area is for *text*.

Comment: I'd look into using `autonumeric.js`, which is a javascript library for making elements numeric only (amongst other things): http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/ (assuming it works on textarea, never tried it as textarea should be used for text, not just numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming inputText is the content of a input field, try:

```
var textareaInput = $("#txtarea").val();

if ((keycode < 48 || keycode > 57) && keycode !== 13 && isNaN(parseInt(textareaInput)))
{
     return false;
}
```

It will return true if the input is a number.

Comment: No need for this. I am asking for textarea field.

Comment: This will solve both copy and pasting issue and the single key input.

Comment: I am still able to paste alphabatical text.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery for reading input of pasted string:

```
$input = $("textarea");
$input.on("input", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if ( ! isNaN(parseInt(value)))
         $(this).val("");
});
```

each time you either enter a character, OR paste something into the text area, it will check to see if the value of the text area is numeric.  If it is, keep it, else dump the entire contents and make it the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beautiful jquery plugin for that purpose: [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask). You might like it

Comment: I have no experience with jquery. Could you please provide a solution.

Comment: `$('textaarea').inputmask({ mask: "9", repeat: 10, greedy: false })` for example, but it will allow you to put maximum 10 digits. If you want more then change repeat param. `mask: 9` means digit in this plugin, `greedy: false` means that it's ok to leave less symbols then it's provided in repeat param.